# Why are PDF thumbnails over-saturated?

Tags: images, media-library, thumbnails, pdf

Often then colors of PDF thumbnails generated by Wordpress are wrong, they look over saturated.

[image]

Is there something I can do to correct that, or is that caused by the PDF itself ?

Comment: WordPress uses either [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/) or [GD](https://libgd.github.io/) to make the thumbnails. You can see which one you're using in Tools, Health Check.

Comment: Best guess that's a print PDF which doesn't use RGB colours and whichever tool is converting them differently to your other software. It's been a long time since I looked at that so I don't know what your options are. Worst case you can drop your own thumbnails into your uploads folder instead overwriting the bad ones, or you might be able to set up some other tool to generate the thumbnails or - as a last resort - you could make sure your PDFs are RGB before you upload them.

Comment: If you have a different command line utility which generates thumbnails the way you want then you could set up a new WP_Image_Editor class for it, with priority for processing PDFs. Ditto if you just had a tool that would pre-process the colour spaces before handing off to your existing tool.